# How to support CJK characters using HtmlRenderer.PDFSharp?

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, html-renderer

With default settings, the HtmlRenderer.PDFSharp would render CJK characters as blank boxes in generated PDF file. What can be done to make them correctly displayed?

Comment: According to their docs, they [do not support](http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/PDFsharpFAQ.ashx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1#Does_PDFsharp_support_for_Arabic_Hebrew_CJK_Chinese_Japanese_Korean_6) CJK.

Comment: @CodingYoshi Who is "their"? PDFsharp does not support RTL text, but CJK characters should show up when using Unicode correctly. I do not know how HtmlRenderer handles Unicode or RTL. HtmlRenderer uses PDFsharp.